# Why are split and tab navigations distinct?

Tags: key-bindings, split, tabbed-user-interface, navigation

Known: `<Ctrl>w` then any of `hjkl`.

Known: `:tab_<CR>` where `_` is either `rlpn`.

Why is there not  a `<Ctrl>` navigation for tabs nor a `:` for splits? Why do the navigation commands differ in terminology?

One does not seek `nmap` solutions; one wants to learn Vim's native wormholes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab navigation is one dimensional, so it has commands which mirror similar commands, `:bn`, `:cp`, etc.

Window navigation is two dimensional, so it has commands that align with the two dimensional normal mode motions, `hjkl`.

It should also be noted, in addition to the commands you listed, there are also both normal mode tab navigation commands: `gt`, `gT`, and command line window navigation commands: `:wincmd h`, `:wincmd j`.

Comment: @fde-capu When navigating tabs you can either move forwards or backwards. `:tabl` moves in the same direction as `:tabn`; it just moves further. Moving down, on the other hand is orthogonal to moving left.

Comment: What does `rlpn` stand for? Arbitrary choices? Is there a reference for what Vim commands 'stand for'?

Comment: Although note that you *can* also navigate through windows one dimensionally, with `<c-w> w` and `<c-w> W`.

Comment: @fde-capu Rewind. Last. Previous. Next. The best reference for this is probably the help. See e.g. `:help :tabr`

Comment: @fde-capu ...or for command-line commands, you can just press your wildchar (by default, `tab`) after typing the abbreviated version and see what it completes to. `:tabr` completes to `:tabrewind`.